# add new rows to dataframe based on condition python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, pandas-groupby

Need to add new rows to dataframe based on condition.

Current dataframe:

[image]

In this dataframe there are 4 columns. what i want to do ischeck the 'Time' column and check the nearest value for 12PM mid night in every night shift and add two new row as 11:59:59 and 00:00:01 with **same values as the that nearest datapoint.**

For examle: Closest value(to 12PM) for 03-01 Night is 21:46:54. so need to add two rows,

```
W25     03-01 Night    RUNNING    23:59:59
W25     03-01 Night    RUNNING    00:00:01
```

so final expected dataframe should be like this:

[image]

Sample data:

```
data={'Machine': {0: 'W5', 343: 'W5', 344: 'W5', 586: 'W5', 587: 'W5'}, 'State': {0: 'start', 343: 'STOPPED', 344: 'RUNNING', 586: 'STOPPED', 587: 'MAINT'}, 'Day-Shift': {0: '03-01 Night', 343: '03-01 Night', 344: '03-01 Night', 586: '03-01 Night', 587: '03-01 Night'}, 'Time': {0: Timestamp('2021-03-01 21:00:00'), 343: Timestamp('2021-03-01 22:16:54'), 344: Timestamp('2021-03-01 23:16:54'), 586: Timestamp('2021-03-01 23:48:45'), 587: Timestamp('2021-03-02 02:28:54')}}
```

Really appreciate your support !!!!!

Comment: do you have a full date time object you can work with, i see the year is missing from your columns ? also night/day is redundant if you have properly formatted date time objects.

Comment: @Manakin Do you have any idea to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `idxmax()` to find the max record per day, then create a datetime object.

```
df1 = df.loc[df.groupby([df['Time'].dt.normalize()])['Time'].idxmax()]
df1 = pd.concat([df1] * 2)

df1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime((df1['Time'].dt.normalize().astype(str) + [' 23:59:59', ' 00:00:01']))
```

---

```
print(df1)

    Machine  State  Day-Shift                Time
587     W25  MAINT  03-01 Day 2021-03-01 23:59:59
587     W25  MAINT  03-01 Day 2021-03-01 00:00:01
```

---

```
df = pd.concat([df,df1]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)


  Machine    State  Day-Shift                Time
0     W25    start  03-01 Day 2021-03-01 07:00:00
1     W25  STOPPED  03-01 Day 2021-03-01 07:16:54
2     W25  RUNNING  03-01 Day 2021-03-01 07:16:54
3     W25  STOPPED  03-01 Day 2021-03-01 07:28:45
4     W25    MAINT  03-01 Day 2021-03-01 07:28:54
5     W25    MAINT  03-01 Day 2021-03-01 23:59:59
6     W25    MAINT  03-01 Day 2021-03-01 00:00:01
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But this gives me this error.     ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (2,)

Comment: i don't see how the above could do that, did you change any lines of code ?

Comment: No i didnt change anything. in 3rd row, df['Time'] containg four columns but in list contains only two elements. i think that is the reason for this error.

Comment: df1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime((df1['Time'].dt.normalize().astype(str) + [' 23:59:59', ' 00:00:01']))  This line gives the above error

Comment: data={'Machine': {0: 'W5', 343: 'W5', 344: 'W5', 586: 'W5', 587: 'W5'}, 'State': {0: 'start', 343: 'STOPPED', 344: 'RUNNING', 586: 'STOPPED', 587: 'MAINT'}, 'Day-Shift': {0: '03-01 Night', 343: '03-01 Night', 344: '03-01 Night', 586: '03-01 Night', 587: '03-01 Night'}, 'Time': {0: Timestamp('2021-03-01 21:00:00'), 343: Timestamp('2021-03-01 22:16:54'), 344: Timestamp('2021-03-01 23:16:54'), 586: Timestamp('2021-03-01 23:48:45'), 587: Timestamp('2021-03-02 02:28:54')}}

Comment: Your code works well when there are no midnight data points. Can you please try to do the same for the above-mentioned data dictionary?

Comment: you have multiple date times i.e the 2nd and the 3rd, I have a solution in mind, but the machine is the same per day?

Comment: Yes for the day machine is same, Using for loop, i filter one machine at a time and the do the calculations for that selected machine and finnaly append it to the finaldataframe

Comment: @domahc not the most elegant, but try `df1 = pd.concat([ y.assign(Time=pd.to_datetime((y['Time'].dt.normalize().astype(str) + [' 23:59:59', ' 00:00:01']))
          ) for x,y in df1.groupby(df1['Time'].dt.day) ])`

Comment: df1 returns 4 rows but it sould be 2 rows like in your answer's df1

Comment: @domahc do you want the max datetime only? because you have different dates on your dataset

Comment: Hi @Manakin Actually what i want to do is get the last data point for each day and add two datapoints to dataframe.Like in my example, if the last entry for 03-01 Night at 22:28 then set another point at 23:59:59 with same other values as last entry and add second data point as next day 00:00:01 as the same other values as prevous data last data point(expect time ).

Comment: @domahc, then that's what my piece of code is doing,

Comment: True. But code didnt work for above i mentioned data dictionary. Can you please re-run your code above data dictionary?

Comment: @domahc i did, it worked, (the snippet I posted above)